# CircleCI fails to import google-cloud-bigquery

Tags: python, circleci

I'm trying to build CI tests for my application that needs to interact with several db types. As such I have a DbImporter package that handles that part. The package works correctly when used inside a Docker instance, but fails when tested in CircleCI and I cant understand why. The setup for both the docker instance and Circle CI is the same (python 3.10.7, same packages installed). Below the traceback provided by CircleCI, *KeyError: PosixPath('/home/circleci/project/tests/unit')* seems to be the root of the traceback coming from bigquery, but i couldn't find anything on the web.

The CI tests work correctly when the google-cloud-bigquery part is removed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/pkgutil.py", line 417, in get_importer
    importer = sys.path_importer_cache[path_item]
KeyError: PosixPath('/home/circleci/project/tests/unit')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/circleci/project/tests/unit/data_ingestion/test_ingestion.py", line 7, in <module>
    from application.data_ingestion.src.DbImporter import DbImporter
  File "/home/circleci/project/application/data_ingestion/src/DbImporter.py", line 2, in <module>
    from google.cloud import bigquery
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 52, in <module>
    import google.api_core.exceptions as core_exceptions
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/exceptions.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.rpc import error_details_pb2
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/rpc/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3260, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3234, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3272, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 572, in _build_master
    ws = cls()
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 621, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1988, in find_distributions
    importer = get_importer(path_item)
  File "/home/circleci/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/lib/python3.10/pkgutil.py", line 421, in get_importer
    importer = path_hook(path_item)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1632, in path_hook_for_FileFinder
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1504, in __init__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 182, in _path_isabs
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Exited with code exit status 1
```

- Tried removing bigquery from the requirements.txt file, the CI test works correctly
- Tried downgrading python to the same version as the instance in which it works